# Why ng-bind-html throw away the HTML tag which I add

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get some data from server like this:

```
{
 "pageIndex": 0,
 "pageSize": 30,
 "recordCount": 0,
 "records": [
 {
  "auditContent": "",
  "auditID": 354,
  "auditStatus": 3,
  "bizStatus": 1,
  "bodyPart": "2",
  "categoryID": 141,
  "city": "上海",
  "desc": "22",
  "duration": 2,
  "forbidden": "2",
  "indications": "2",
  "name": "<div><span style='color:red;'>头部</span></div>按摩"
}
]
}
```

And I use Angular.js to show the result with HTML tag.Code like this:

```
 <td ng-bind-html='spuWebDTO.name'></td>
```

However,it's not work.I found the view result throw away the HTML tag `<div><span style='color:red;'></span></div>`.Only show the text:`头部按摩`

Why and how to solve this problem.

Comment: do you want to display name as is? I mean with the html tags and all those? If thats the case, you can just use ng-bind.

Comment: do you have `$sanitize` available? check this link: [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: I want to show the html. In my code,I want `头部` show with read color.

Comment: I have already add ngSanitize like `var app = angular.module('Index', ['ngSanitize']);`.Is there some wrong the way I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$sce) {
  $scope.obj = {
 "pageIndex": 0,
 "pageSize": 30,
 "recordCount": 0,
 "records": [
 {
  "auditContent": "",
  "auditID": 354,
  "auditStatus": 3,
  "bizStatus": 1,
  "bodyPart": "2",
  "categoryID": 141,
  "city": "上海",
  "desc": "22",
  "duration": 2,
  "forbidden": "2",
  "indications": "2",
   "name": "<div><span style='color:red;'>头部</span></div>按摩"
}
] 
}
 $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.obj.records[0].name);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-bind-html="content"></p> 
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I according to your suggest and coding like yours.But It is doesn't work as well.code like this:
`<div ng-app="Index" ng-controller="IndexController">
        <p ng-bind-html="content"></p>`

Comment: its working here. Check the code. 
you wrote this on your code ? $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.obj.records[0].name);

Comment: I find the reason. The server response add some escape character in HTML tag,so it can't work.I use ` spuWebDTO.name.replace(/\xA0/g, " ").replace(/&gt;/g, ">")
                        .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
                        .replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ")
                        .replace(/&quot;/g, "\"")
                        .replace(/&#39;/g, "\'");
`
and it worked.

Comment: And what's more.It is no need to use `$sce`,and my module definition is `var app = angular.module('Index', ['ngSanitize']);`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to add ngSanitize to your app module,

```
`angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML =
   'I am an <code>HTML</code>string with ' +
   '<a href="#">links!</a> and other <em>stuff</em>';
}]);`
```

the you can use `ng-bind-html` in your template

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already add this module.code is `var app = angular.module('Index', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('IndexController', function ($scope, $http) .....` But the view result don't show the `<div><span style='color:red;'></span></div>`. In my code,I want `头部` show with read color.

Comment: in your controller inject $sce provider like this example

`controller('AppController', ['$http', '$templateCache', '$sce',
  function($http, $templateCache, $sce) {
    var self = this;
    self.explicitlyTrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(
        '<span onmouseover="this.textContent=&quot;Explicitly trusted HTML bypasses ' +
        'sanitization.&quot;">Hover over this text.</span>');
  }]);`

Comment: check "Show me an example using SCE" example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce